# Hide Loading spinner after ajax complete event

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm using JQuery Mobile 1.4.0 to build cross platform app and will be build by phonegap. For example I had two pages, one is #homepage, another is #detail page

```
<div id="home" data-role="page> Home Page 
   <a href="#detail">Go Detail</a>
</div>
<div id="detail" data-role="page> Detail Page </div>
```

JQuery Mobile default use ajax to load pages into DOM which is fine, my problem is that, before detail page show, I need get data from remote server via ajax call. I register ajaxStart and ajaxComplete event on document to show and show/hide spinner.

```
$(document).ajaxStart(function(){
  $.mobile.loading('show');
});
$(document).ajaxComplete(function(){
  $.mobile.loading('hide');
});
```

The problem is jquery mobile hide the loading spinner before ajaxComplete called in transition method, so actually $.mobile.loading('hide') will be called twice. That's not good because data haven't been populated into DOM so the detail page will be white blank then after a while data was inserted.

If you don't know what I'm saying, you could look into jquery mobile source code and you can see line 5070

```
this._triggerCssTransitionEvents( to, from, "before" );

// TODO put this in a binding to events *outside* the widget
this._hideLoading();
```

So my question is how to really hide the loading spinner after ajaxComplete not after page transition?

Thanks very much for your help.

Comment: In one of my recent apps I hid the spinner in the `$(document).load` event and also on the `$(document).ajaxStop` event, worked without any issues.

Comment: @EthanZ This has frustrated me for a while now, have you resolved this?

Answer (score 0):

change from using `complete` to `stop` which will stop the loading spinner from hiding too soon.

```
$(document).ajaxStart(function() {
    $.mobile.loading('show');
});

$(document).ajaxStop(function() {
    $.mobile.loading('hide');
});
```

Comment: It's not working because jquery mobile actually hide the spinner when navigate between pages because of transition.